# listen to kernel.request event on Silex?

Tags: symfony, silex

I want to listen to kernel.request event on Silex microframework http://silex.sensiolabs.org/documentation

How ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access the dispatcher service as `$app['dispatcher']` and you can see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) how to use it. But I think you should use Silex's [`before`](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#before-and-after-filters) event instead as it's called on [`kernel.request`](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Application.php#L438) as well ([here](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html#accepting-a-json-request-body) is a good expample how to use it).

**UPDATE:**

The links above are outdated. Before filters moved to a new [middlewares section](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#before-middleware) and here is how you can write one:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    // do what you want ...

    // if you want you can return a response so the controller won't be called
    // return new Response($content);

    // or just return null
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `on($eventName, $callback, $priority = 0)` method on silex application which you can use to listen to any event. On this particular case it will be as following.

```
$app->on(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents::REQUEST, function (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event) use ($app) {
    // Your actions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the **Silex Middleware** [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/middlewares.html):

Silex allows you to run code, that changes the default Silex behavior, at different stages during the handling of a request through middleware:

- **Application middleware** is triggered independently of the current handled request;
- Route middleware is triggered when its associated route is matched.

## Application Middleware

Application middleware is only run for the **master** Request.

### Before Middleware

A before application middleware allows you to tweak the Request **before the controller is executed**:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    // ...
});
```

By default, the middleware is run **after the routing and the security**.

If you want your middleware to be run **even if an exception is thrown early** on (on a 404 or 403 error for instance), then, you need to register it as an early event:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    // ...
}, Application::EARLY_EVENT);
```

In this case, the **routing and the security won't have been executed**, and so **you won't have access** to the `locale`, the `current route`, or the `security user`.